# Stoping .htaccess from sending redirect (302) header

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, curl, http-headers

I'm creating an API, and I'm testing CRUD the functionality with an external client.

To be able to skip *index.php* in the URL, and only use '.../producer/id' etc I changed redirection in the .htaccess file *(se below)* which works accept for the fact that no other header code than 201 - Created can be sent out from the server. If I try to send out any other code it automatically becomes the following code:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2012 19:42:10 GMT Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1 X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.1 Location: /producers/ Content-Length: 565 Content-Type: application/json
```

As an example is the php code below. If I add a '!' before $result so that the statement becomes false the header in the else statement should be sent out, which doesn't happen. Again, this 302 header is sent out. If I leave it as is the 201 header is sent out, just as it should.

Why is this happening?

**php:**

```
if ($result) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 201 Created');
        header('Location: /producers/' . $id);
}
else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');
    header('Location: /producers/' . $id
}
```

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

    # Allow images and statics to be addressable
    RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # You have to manually change to our username or directory where our controller index is host

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: To clarify, you only get a 302 code when the code should have been 400, 404 or 500? You get a code 200 and the redirection works otherwise?

Comment: Actually It's only 201 that works. All other codes "becomes" 302.

Comment: What's the URL that is causing the 302? Does it happen to be `/producers` (no trailing slash)?

Comment: I checked and it is 'Location: /producers/'

Comment: What is the original URL that gets redirected to `/producers/`? `/producers`?

Comment: /producers is the root, but it works with /producers/ too as well as /producers/id etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Location: always triggers a redirect, which is always a 3xx status code.

If you want to output any other code, append it to the other header, and don't send a Location:

```
if ($result) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 201 Created', 201);
} elseif ($errors) {
    header('Location: /theform.php'); // 301 by default
} else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', 500);
}
```